# When is $\: \pi_1(\langle X,\mathcal{T}\hspace{.01 in}\rangle,x_0) \:$ a topological group?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups

(Although I am taking an algebraic topology class, this is not homework;

we have not gotten to this yet.)

Let $\langle X,\mathcal{T}_X\rangle$ be a path-connected Hausdorff space. $\:$ Let $x_0$ be a member of $X$. $\:$ Let $L$ be the set

[loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_%28topology%29) in $X$ with endpoints $x_0$. $\;\;\;$ Define $\;\; \operatorname{concat} \; : \; L\times L \; \to \; L \;\;$ to be loop concatenation.

Define the relation $\:\sim\:$ on $L$ to be [homotopicness relative to endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy). $\;\;$ Define $\mathcal{T}_L$ to

be the [compact-open topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology) on $L$. $\:$ It follows that $\:\sim\:$ is an equivalence relation on $L$.

Define $\;\; [\cdot] \; : \; L \; \to \; L/\sim \;\;$ to be the quotient map.

It follows that for all members $\hspace{.4 in} f_0,f_1,g_0,g_1$ of $L$, $\;\;$ if $\: f_0 \sim f_1 \:$ and $\: g_0 \sim g_1 \:$ then $\operatorname{concat}(f_0,g_0) \sim \operatorname{concat}(f_1,g_1) \:$.

Define $\;\; \star \; : \; (L/\sim) \times (L/\sim) \; \to \; L/\sim \;\;$ by $\;\; [f]\star [g] \: = \: [\operatorname{concat}(f,g)] \;\;$.

It follows that $\langle (L/\sim),\star \rangle$ is a group and that $[t\mapsto x_0]$ is its identity element.

Define $\mathcal{T}_G$ to be the quotient topology on $\: L/\sim \:$ from $\mathcal{T}_L$.

> When is $\langle (L/\sim),\star,\mathcal{T}_G \rangle$ a not-necessarily-Hausdorff topological group?
>   
>   When is $\{[t\mapsto x_0]\}$ closed with respect to $\mathcal{T}_G\:$?

I have convinced myself that both of those happen at least when:

for every point $x$ in $X$, there is an open subsets $U$ of $X$ such that $\: x\in U \:$ and $U$  simultaneously

witnesses [local path connectedness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space) and [semi-local simply connectedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-locally_simply_connected) of $\langle X,\mathcal{T}_X\rangle$.

(because I have convinced myself that $\langle (L/\sim),\mathcal{T}_G\rangle$ is discrete in that case)

Comment: See this MathOverflow question, and its answers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26680/fundamental-group-as-topological-group (if you think the link answers your question, then add a community wiki answer with a the link, and accept it—you'll have to wait a bit for this—so that this one does not remain unanswered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26680/fundamental-group-as-topological-group